# Training of vs Training for

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

- training **for** all users across..
- training **of** all users across..

Are these interchangeable and grammatically correct?

Comment: (b) as far as one can tell without reasonable context, yes. (a) not in all contexts. 'There will be training for all users ...' // 'Training of / for all users ... is envisaged.' Here, 'of' indicates that all users are intended to participate; 'for' indicates that training is provided (and doubtless encouraged) for all users. // 'The training is for all users' is ambiguous; mandatory _or_ universally accessible.

Comment: We usually speak of 'training _of_ [people] _for_ [a task], but you can say 'training for users' in the sense of 'for the benefit of users'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you, it makes sense. For more context the overall sentence is "....including training of all users across all regions is impractical." and the reason for my question is that someone I work with asked me to change it from 'of' to 'for'.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you for your comment. It's insightful.